# Microdata usage for a blog post

Tags: html, blogs, microdata

I have a blog page and I am not sure if I understood the schema.org microdata correctly. I have a few cases in which I am unsure and I think it would be good to discuss them. My code:

```
<body lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
    <section class="blog" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
        <article class="post" itemprop="blogPosts" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <header>
                <time class="publish-date" datetime="2011-11-06T13:42:04+01:00" itemprop="datePublished">
                    November 2011
                </time>
                <h1 itemprop="name"><a href=blog/post-slug.html" itemprop="url">
                    My Title Here
                </a></h1>
            </header>

            <section itemprop="description">
                <p>The lead text here</p>
            </section>

            <section itemprop="articleBody">
                <p>The other text here</p>
            </section>

            <footer>
                This article is published by
                <span itemprop="author">
                    John Doe
                </span>
                at 
                <time datetime="2012-10-01T15:33:04+02:00" itemprop="datePublished">
                    1 October 2012 on 15:33
                </time>
                and listed in the category 
                <a href=""><span itemprop="articleSection">
                    My Category
                </span></a>.
                The article is licensed under the <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/" target="_blank">Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0</a>.
            </footer>
        </article>

        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <ul class="comments" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
            <li itemprop="comment">
                <span itemprop="creator">Jane Doe</span>
                <time itemprop="commentTime" datetime="2011-05-08T19:30">May 8, 7:30pm</time>
                <article itemprop="commentText">
                    <p>A very good comment here</p>
                </article>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
```

1. Can I have multiple itemprop attributes? I am making the author copyright holder as well, but I am not sure if that is possible;
2. The list of comments is a user comments scope, the individual items are the itemprop of the comment, but I am not sure if that is possible;
3. I split the lead text and the body in my articles, so I can make a listing of blog posts easily. I indicated the lead as a "description" and the body as the (complete?) article body, but I am not sure if articleBody is accounted for the complete text (including lead) or the text without the lead.
4. Are there any other mistakes I have made?

Suggestions and corrections are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Even generic HTML syntax forbids using the same attribute twice in an element. You can however nest elements and have the same attribute in nested elements.

The validator http://validator.w3.org also finds some other markup errors in your code.

There does not seem to be any evidence of schema.org markup being recognized by search engines except when found on large commercial or community sites.

Comment: I have removed the `copyrightHolder` property from the author's name. The `<time>` element have been changed quite a lot over time during the html5 WHATWG discussions, where `pubdate` was first allowed and not anymore (apparently). I have updated the example code, but however I am still interested in the comnments and article lead/body type of configuring micro data.